# Why are antlr3 c# parser methods private?

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr3

I'm building a parser in antlr which compiles to a working java target.  When I retarget for c#2 it produces a parser in which all of the parse methods are private but marked with a [GrammarRule("rulename")] attribute.

What is the approved means to actually invoke the parser?

I am using ANTLR 3.3 Nov 30, 2010 12:45:30

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Make at least one parser rule "public" like this:

```
grammar T;

options {
  language=CSharp2;
}

public parse
  :  privateRule+ EOF
  ;

privateRule
  :  Token+
  ;

// ...
```

You can then call `parse()` on the generated parser.

`protected` and `private` (the default if nothing is specified) are also supported.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find any documentation to this effect.

Comment: @Andy, you're welcome. Yeah, it works a bit differently than the Java target where you _can_ use these keywords, but are not implemented. ANTLR's Java target by default produces the `public` modifier. So it should still work with the Java target if you put a `public` before some parser rule.